Python face_recoginition not matching all the images present in a dir
I am trying to find all the group pic that contains a particular face. I have all those pic in "D:\\Camera" dir. I have my code in "E:\\ImageFinder\main.py" and my reference image at "E:\\ImageFinder\referencePic\image.png". I have created a code that runs almost forever because the "Camera" dir contains more than 500 images. It makes it take forever.
My code without Threads:
from typing import Generator, List
import face_recognition
import os
import threading
import asyncio
from time import sleep

class ImageMatcher:
    def __init__(self, sourceImagePath, targerDirPath) -> None:
        self.sourceImagePath = sourceImagePath
        self.targetDirPath = targerDirPath
        self.imageTypes = ["jpg", "png", "jpeg"]
        self.matchmaking = False
        self.matchedImages = []
        self.known_image = face_recognition.load_image_file(self.sourceImagePath)
        self.known_encoding = face_recognition.face_encodings(self.known_image)[0]

    def getTargetImageFilePaths(self):
        files: List[str] = os.listdir(self.targetDirPath)
        for file in files:
            for ext in self.imageTypes:
                if f".{ext}" in file.lower().strip():
                    yield os.path.join(self.targetDirPath, file)
                    break


    def imagesMatch(self, targetImage: str) -> bool:
        unknown_image = face_recognition.load_image_file(targetImage)
        unknown_encoding = face_recognition.face_encodings(unknown_image, model = "small")
        if len(unknown_encoding) > 0:
            unknown_encoding = unknown_encoding[0]
        else:
            return False
        
        matched = any(face_recognition.compare_faces([self.known_encoding], unknown_encoding))
        if matched:
            print("found")
            self.matchedImages.append(targetImage)
        
        return matched


    def searchAll(self):
        imgFiles = self.getTargetImageFilePaths()
        result = []
        for imgFile in imgFiles:
            result.append(self.imagesMatch(imgFile))

        print(result)
        return result

matchMyFace = ImageMatcher("registeredPics\\103\\image.png", "D:\\Camera")
matchMyFace.searchAll()

I tried putting the "imageMatch" in _thread, and even in async io. But nothing changed there. The code in threading or asyncio processes only 15-20 images... no error raised.
Something I noticed when threading is that after the 15-20 images are matched the print statement does not print when placed below the line: unknown_encoding = face_recognition.face_encodings(unknown_image, model = "small"), and a print statement above it works fine in all the 500 images. Hope this info is helpful.
The issue is:

Why is putting "imageMatch" in a thread or asyncio not working?
Is there any other way to match one image to 500 other images parallelly?
Is there some sort of limit to the multithreading?

> Thanks For your support :)
